# How to dynamically load/render Laravel Collective form?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

I'm devising a small CMS for the in-house development team, where all have experience working with `laravel`.

The CMS requires a small feature where the services that are listed can have a quotation form attached. Instead of creating a completely separate module to add elements & other separately, I wanted to have the system in a manner that the developer adds the laravel collective form code, which we store in the database.

While retrieving, we render the form server side.

Here's my implementation

Controller

```
    public function show($id)
{
    $data['page'] = Service::where('slug', $id)->first();
    if ($data['page']) {
     ....
     $data['form'] = $data['page']->quoteform()->first();

    ....
```

And in the view

```
 {!! $form['html'] !!}
```

But this is definitely won't help, so I tried this approach of rendering the collective form

```
 $data['form'] = View::make('website.includes.render-form',['form'=>$data['page']->quoteform()->first()]);
```

But I'm not sure if this should work, as I couldn't make it work.

Looking forward to a solution if at all the approach I choose is possible, if yes or can be done, would like to know more on the same.

TIA

**Edit 1:**

I used the following blade command `Blade::compileString('string here')` which helped to a certain extent.

where I'm getting the following result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can render the HTML of a view using `render()` method. So you can update to this :

```
$data['form'] = View::make('website.includes.render-form',
                    ['form' => $data['page']->quoteform()->first()]
                )->render();
```

Now the `$data['form']` will have rendered HTML which you can use in blade using `{!! $data['html'] !!}` if you are passing `$data` to your main view.

Comment: It won't work, it's not rendering laravel collective  form codes to html